# In WPF, how can I determine what column/row in a grid a control is in?

Tags: wpf, grid

I am building a grid dynamically and putting buttons in one of the columns.  When I click a button, I want to know what row of my grid it's in.  How can I find this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Click event handler for the button you say:

```
int row;
Button btn = sender as Button;
if (btn != null)
{
    row = Grid.GetRow(btn); // And you have the row number...
}
else
{
    // A nasty error occurred...
}
```