# Data template parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

There is list with columns to display. I am using `ListView` with data templates for cells. And my problem is to *access* both: row and column from template.

Below is demo, xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <GridViewColumn x:Key="Column" x:Shared="False">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding WhatHere}" /> <!-- problem here -->
                        <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView />
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> Items { get; } = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        var a = (GridViewColumn)listView.FindResource("Column");
        a.Header = "a";
        ((GridView)listView.View).Columns.Add(a);

        var b = (GridViewColumn)listView.FindResource("Column");
        b.Header = "b";
        ((GridView)listView.View).Columns.Add(b);
    }
}
```

will produce

[image]

My aim is to have:

```
a     b
a1    b1
a2    b2
a3    b3
```

Possible? How do I *pass* column to `DataTemplate` ? In fact I want to simply know to which column current cell belongs, but please consider following:

1. This is simplified case.
2. In reality data templates are more complicated: many elements with bindings, triggers, etc.
3. In reality column related data are more complicated than just header.
4. Columns will be generated at runtime with different headers, etc.
5. Adding columns and setting `Header` in code-behind is not a problem, `DataTemplate` is.

I was thinking to use attached property on `GridViewColumn`, however, it's not parent of cells in the visual tree:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just bind to an instance of a type that has a property for both the row- and the column index?

Comment: @mm8, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: How about `Converter`? and use of `{RelativeSource Self}` as a parameter? Then you would have access to the UIElement and in the converter `Grid.GetRow(UIElement)` or `Grid.GetColumn()` respectively?

Comment: I even want to say possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/363100/2029607

Comment: The main issue here is that you're going backwards. You are creating a view, and then trying to set your data based on that. WPF isn't designed to work that way, and it's always going to be painful to try to force it to. You need to start with the data. Create a data structure, your view model, that describes the relationships you want, including what column each element is in. Then, bind that data to the view, using the properties in the data to ensure each data element is displayed in the right place. Then the data elements _start_ with all the information you want.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, `Grid` != `GridView` and the problem is that `GridViewColumn` simply contain cell data template, it's not cell container in the view, `RelativeSource` (my first thought as well) won't help.

Comment: My bad for not reading it properly. I had a look at the `GridView` on MSDN and I have found that [`GridViewRowPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewrowpresenter?view=netframework-4.7) has a property called columns. Would that be of use to you?

Comment: @XAMlMAX, in what way it can be useful? See edit, I've attached screenshot of visual tree from some `ListView`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I simply want to use same data template for different columns. If `a1` and `b1` (first row) cells have same `DataContext`, how could they know to which column they belong? This is why I need to pass some kind of *parameter* to data template.

Comment: I can't see that screen shot as I am behind a proxy. And the `GridViewRowPresenter` has `Columns` property which you can use to get the column name or column header from.

Comment: In my experience, almost always, when I find myself wanting to pass information _from_ the view back _to_ the model/data, I've chosen poorly. And I admit, I've chosen poorly more than once. I've regretted it every time. I don't feel there's enough context in your question to really understand it. You've vaguely stated some constraints, but even so the fact that you are building UI in code-behind is very suspect. All that said, I did post [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44581811) recently, and you might find some useful suggestions there.

Comment: I have found [this alteration Index answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719147/2029607) that would give you the row index. The answer is for `ListBox` though.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to pass parameter to data template, then you need more MVVM (c) unknown wpf programmer

@mm8, was right, my design lack one more abstraction to hold column information (column name). I've to create column view model (simplified again):

```
public class ViewModelColumn
{
    public string Column { get; }

    public ViewModelColumn(string column)
    {
        Column = column;
    }
}
```

and the code to add column will become something like

```
var a = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
a.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new ViewModelColumn("a"));
((GridView)listView.View).Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = "a",
    CellTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = a }
});
```

Cell data template is created in code behind. The idea is to supply `ContentControl` for all cells with column instance bound to `Content`, then the view needs another data template (this time fully defined in xaml), to know how to visualize it:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelColumn}">
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{Binding Column, Mode=OneTime}" />
        <Run Text="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Such cell `DataContext` contains *column* information. To access *row* (access item from `Items`), we have to use `ListViewItem.DataContext`.

Now the view will looks like this:

[image]

I am pretty happy about this solution, mostly about combination of things what makes it working, but I guess it could be improved. Hopefully after posting the answer the question become *clearer*.